# Usage of shared pointers in vectors to access class objects

Tags: c++, c++11

So for a class assignment we have started using shared_pointers within vectors like so: `vector<shared_ptr<BankAccount>> @accountsVector` where my professor explains that the vector contains a list of shared pointers and each pointer points to a class BankAccount object. My question is, how do I access those objects in the BankAccount class? I have tried using an Index in a for loop with arrow notation and dot notation. If there's similar question point me in the right direction please.

Comment: A smart pointer is used just like a regular pointer.

Comment: Put some code you're having trouble with into a [mcve], along with any compile errors you're getting.

Comment: The same BankAccount object? I can't figure out from this description if `shared_ptr` even makes sense. Otherwise, the comment about smart pointers being used the same holds.The real issue likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: Arrow notation should have done the job. Try it once more and if the problem's still there edit your question to describe that specific attempt.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if `BankAccount` has a member `getBalance()`, then you can do things like this:

```cpp
vector<std::shared_ptr<BankAccount>> accountsVector;
...
accountsVector.push_back(std::make_shared<BankAccount>());
accountsVector.push_back(std::make_shared<BankAccount>());
...
double balance;
balance = accountsVector[0]->getBalance();
balance = accountsVector[1]->getBalance();
// etc...
```

```cpp
vector<std::shared_ptr<BankAccount>> accountsVector;
...
accountsVector.push_back(std::make_shared<BankAccount>());
accountsVector.push_back(std::make_shared<BankAccount>());
...
for(auto &account : accountsVector)
{
    double balance = account->getBalance();
    //...
}
```